# Based on git-flow, do we really have to create anything under `feature` prefix?

Tags: git-workflow

Our team keep asking me, why refactor tasks, or fixes has to be prefixed as `/feature` if they are not feature and my unofficial answer is that git-workflow rules.
But to be honest I think these rules are not updated or not clear or accurate. Why do really need to have only feature/ prefix when we have a lot type of tasks that we want to branch with the correct description for that task.

[image]

Why a bug fix should be under feature based on git-workflow and not `fix/task_1122-fix-payment-response`

Especially when [semanticeVersioning](https://semver.org/) counts commits based on their prefix, like `fix:`, `feat:` etc.

I would like to hear your opinion about that